# DropDown Multiselect as reduxform's field issue

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

```
    <Fabric>
        <Dropdown
            placeholder="Select options"
            label="Multi-select uncontrolled example"
            multiSelect
            options={options}
            onChange={(value) => {return this.props.input.onChange(value)}}
        />
   </Fabric>
```

The above is the code snippet of the multiselect using Dropdown from fabric.

```
private _OnChangeOption(
    event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>,
    option?: IDropdownOption
  ): void {
    let x = this.props.input.value;
    if(!Array.isArray(x)) {
      x = [x];
    }
    option !== undefined && x.push(option.key);
    this.props.input.onChange(x);
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

This is the onChange event handler. 
When I do this, both the initial and the updated values have the same data(updated selected list of options). This happens only if the the field is a multiselect dropdown. If it is a text string/single select dropdown, it works perfectly.